# Sending correct escape sequences in terminal

Tags: bash, keyboard, terminal, escape-characters, ansi

## Issue

To scroll a few lines up in [WeeChat](https://weechat.org) one is supposed to press `<Alt> + <PgUp>`. When I press these keys, the program thinks I'm pressing `<Alt> + ,` instead.

## Debugging

In my terminal, typing `<PgUp>` is received as `meta2-5~`. This works fine and represents the `<PgUp>` escape sequence: `<Esc>[5~`. (So, it is my understanding that `meta2` is `<Esc>[`.)

Typing `<Alt> + <PgUp>` is received as `meta-,` instead of `meta-meta2-5~`. (Typing `<Alt> + ,` is also received as `meta-,`, so it is my understanding that `<Alt>` corresponds to `meta` here.) The reasons `<Alt>` is received as `meta-` is because I've checked "Send Alt as Meta" in Terminal.app settings.

Now (hold on for such strange behaviour), if I press `<Esc>`, this guy is received as `meta`! So, to scroll up a few lines I can press `<Esc> + <PgUp>` a few times. (I cannot simply keep `<Esc>` pressed and hit a few `<PgUp>`s. I need to repress `<Esc>` as well.)

## TL;DR

- `<PgUp>` is escaped correctly as `meta2-5~`.
- `<Alt> + <PgUp>` is escaped incorrectly as `meta-,` (should be `meta-meta2-5~`).
- `<Alt> + ,` is escaped correctly as `meta-,`.
- `<Esc> + <PgUp>` is escaped incorrectly (?) as `meta-meta2-5~`.

## Setup

I'm sitting on a Mac, using Terminal.app, ssh-ing into a CentOS 7.6.1810, connected to a tmux session, running WeeChat in one window.

## Additional info

[Here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) the whole list of ANSI escape sequences can be found. Strangely, `<PgUp>` seems to be encoded as `0;73`, and not the expected `<Esc>[5~`. So, I'm not sure what's going on in this website as well.

## Additional context for [sawdust answer](https://superuser.com/a/1469994/224792)

> You seem to be misunderstanding the required keystrokes and which keys generate characters.

Point taken.

---

> So did you hold down the `<Alt>` key, type the `<PgUp>` key, and then release the `<Alt>` key?
>   If the program responds as if you are *"pressing `<Alt> + ,`"*, then you apparently did something else.

I indeed did "hold down the `<Alt>` key, type the `<PgUp>` key, and then release the `<Alt>` key".

I'm wondering whether MacOS caught that key combination and did send something else to my terminal, like that `<Alt> + ,`.

---

> The `<Esc>` key is not a modifier key, and should not be kept *"pressed"*.

Got it.

---

> The two-byte code for the `<PgUp>` key is `0x0 0x49` or decimal `0 73`.

Do you understand what `<Esc>[5~` may refer to, then?
[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123160/115816) points out that sometimes it's necessary to enforce Mac's *Terminal.app* to send correct escape sequences, and precisely `<PgUp>` as `\033[5~`, which it's what is already happening on my machine. I'm wondering now what sequence should be sent when `<Alt> + <PgUp>` is pressed instead.

These are "bindings" between keystrokes and... ?

Thanks for clearing my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

[*WeeChat*](https://weechat.org/) expects a `\033[5;3~` escape sequence (see [source code](https://github.com/weechat/weechat/blob/57aa9e060ef7214f8b822fa32b40bb728482adce/src/gui/curses/gui-curses-key.c#L167-L170)) to scroll a few lines up.
You can configure your terminal application to send such escape sequence (if it's not already doing so) when pressing `<Alt> + <PgUp>`.

For Apple's *Terminal.app* go to *Terminal > Preferences... > Profiles > Keyboard* to add such missing key-action pair.
(Use `\033[6;3~` for `<Alt> + <PgDn>`.)

## Credit

I ought to thank **sawdust** for [his comprehensive answer](https://superuser.com/a/1469994/224792) and having me directed towards the solution of this issue.
Debugging help has also been provided by the folk on `#weechat@chat.freenode.net`.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be misunderstanding the required keystrokes and which keys generate characters.

Key concepts about standard terminal keyboards:
The `<Shift>`, `<Ctrl>`, and `<Alt>` keys do not generate any characters (by themselves).
These keys generate an alternate character code when combined with another key.
The notation used for describing such a combination of keys is:

```
 <modifier_key> + <char_key>
```

The notation means that you should hold down the `<modifier_key>`, type (i.e. press and release) the `<char_key>`, and then release the `<modifier_key>`.
The plus sign, `+`, as used in this notation indicates the key combination, and does not indicate a key that should be typed or pressed as a keystroke for this combination.

---

> ... one is supposed to press `<Alt> + <PgUp>`. When I press these keys, the program thinks I'm pressing `<Alt> + ,` instead

So did you hold down the `<Alt>` key, type the `<PgUp>` key, and then release the `<Alt>` key?
If the program responds as if you are *"pressing `<Alt> + ,`"*, then you apparently did something else.

Note that (contrary to your assumptions), a modifier key does not necessarily prepend characters to form an escape sequence.  The modifier key can generate a unique character code based on the type key.
For instance `<Shift> + <A>` generates an upper-case `A` character.  Without the `<Shift>` modifier key, a low-case `a` character would be generated.   Whereas `<Ctrl> + <A>` generates an ASCII `SOH` (start of header) character.

---

> The reasons `<Alt>` is received as `meta-` is because I've checked "Send Alt as Meta" in Terminal.app settings.

On a PC the keyboard hardware generates scancodes so that *every* keypress (and release) can be detected.
It is up to software to translate and remap the keypresses.
That means that the previous comments on how the `<Shift>`, `<Ctrl>`, and `<Alt>` keys behave on a standard terminal may not apply in all cases.
You seem to be describing such a nonstandard, customized handling of keyboard scancodes.

On PCs compound modified keys can be defined, i.e. `<Ctrl> + <Shift> + <A>`.  On Teletype terminals only a few such key combinations generated actual character codes.

Apparently this option you describe is to replace the functionality of the `<Alt>` key.  Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key):

> The Meta key is a modifier key on certain keyboards.
>   ...
>   Generally the Meta key worked similar to Macintosh's `Command` key, in that when held down it modified letters and symbols into immediate commands (shortcuts). On these keyboards you could get many commands per letter by combinations of Meta with other modifier keys such as `Hyper` and `Super`.

---

> ... if I press `<Esc>`, this guy is received as `meta!`

The `<Esc>` key is a key that generates a (control) character.  It is not a modifier key like the `<Shift>`, `<Ctrl>`, and `<Alt>` keys.

So a sequence such as `<Esc> + <PgUp>` needs to be entered by typing the `<Esc>` key, and then typing the `<PgUp>` key.  (The plus sign is actually superfluous in this case, if not incorrect, and the keystrokes should be written simply as `<Esc> <PgUp>`.

> I cannot simply keep `<Esc>` pressed and hit a few `<PgUp>`s. I need to repress `<Esc>` as well.

The `<Esc>` key is not a modifier key, and should not be kept *"pressed"*.

---

> Here the whole list of ANSI escape sequences can be found. Strangely, `<PgUp>` seems to be encoded as `0;73`, and not the expected `<Esc>[5~`. So, I'm not sure what's going on in this website as well.

You seem to be misunderstanding that web page.
The data generated by key presses and key releases on a PC keyboard undergo several mappings or translations before being "read" by an application program.
Initially the keyboard hardware generates [scancodes](http://www.vetra.com/scancodes.html).
The Keyboard Service Routine of the OS will convert the scancode to a two-byte value or [Auxiliary byte values](http://www.philipstorr.id.au/pcbook/book3/table1.htm).  Many of these values were established by register **AL** and **AH**  contents returned by the keyboard service routine of the original IBM PC BIOS.
The two-byte code for the `<PgUp>` key is `0x0 0x49` or decimal `0 73`.
If you expect `<PgUp>` to generate an escape character sequence, then you could use the `Set Keyboard Strings` command described on that web page you cited.

The ANSI escape sequences (in general) are for the control of the display side of the terminal.
In general the terminal keyboard does not generate escape sequences (unless there is no ASCII character for that key, or the key has been reprogrammed).

---

**ADDENDUM**

> Do you understand what `<Esc>[5~` may refer to, then?

Not really.
Your question is complicated since it's a mashup of how keystrokes translate to (ANSI) Escape code sequences.  The problems are that:

- (a) software can translate the received keyboard scancodes into anything it chooses,

For examples of how various scancode sequences (i.e. key presses and releases) can be translated/interpreted for different software environments, see [JavaScript Keyboard Events](https://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).
The takeaway is stated in the conclusion:

> It's truely impressive what a hash has been made of a simple thing like recognizing a key pressed on the keyboard. You'd think computer technology would have advanced far enough by now to have this all worked out better.

Additionally, the ANSI terminal standard(s) provides user-capability to redefine what character(s) individual keys will generate (i.e. the `Set Keyboard Strings` command described on that web page you cited).

- and (b) `<Esc>[5~` could be classified as an ANSI Control Sequence for "private use" (by the defining terminal).

ANSI standards define the two-character sequence of `ESC` and `[` as the "Prefix to an ESCape sequence" and "Control Sequence Introducer", aka CSI.
The terminating `~`, or 0x7E, character would seem to categorize this sequence as a "private" one that the terminal (or terminal emulation program) can define for its own use.

---

Apparently the "Send Alt as Meta" option you mention is to replace the functionality of the `<Alt>` key.  Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key):

> The Meta key is a modifier key on certain keyboards.
>   ...
>   Generally the Meta key worked similar to Macintosh's `Command` key, in that when held down it modified letters and symbols into immediate commands (shortcuts). On these keyboards you could get many commands per letter by combinations of Meta with other modifier keys such as `Hyper` and `Super`.
>   ...
>   Software often provided another workaround, such as using the Alt key

So presumably there would be configuration capability to define the strings that these Meta key combinations would respond with (e.g. similar to the ANSI `Set Keyboard Strings` command described on that web page you cited).

---

> Typing `<Alt> + <PgUp>` is received as `meta-,` instead of `meta-meta2-5~`.

Modifier keys can actually generate entirely new character sequences for the key combinations, and may not simply prepend a fixed substring.
So just because  "`<PgUp>` is received as [or generates] `meta2-5~`", you cannot use that to predict what the Meta version of `<PgUp>` is.

So I'm guessing that somewhere in that terminal emulation program there's a definition for `<Meta> + <PgUp>` that is not what you expect.

Comment: Thanks so much for addressing my confusion. I've added a section to my question where I'm providing some additional context regarding your points. I know this is not a forum, but I think we haven't yet understood what's going on. Namely, why I cannot scroll *WeeChat* with `<Alt> + <PgUp>`. The nice thing is that *WeeChat* lets me see what keys / signals are received, letting me hopefully debug this.

Comment: *"...but I think we haven't yet understood what's going on"* -- True, so I've given it another shot.  I've had problems grasping your issue, and I admit I'm not a keyboard driver expert.

Comment: I found the solution! I'm not sure whether I should reply my own answer now (given the help you gave me figuring this out). In short `<Alt> + <PgUp>` was caught (by the OS?) and not sent through the terminal app. Adding the key-action `<Alt> + <PgUp>`-`\033\033[5~` (`<PgDn>`/`\033[6~`) did the trick, which was what I was already doing manually with `<Esc> <PgUp>` (no `+`, as you mentioned). So, if you include this line at the opening of your answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Found *actual* solution. `<Alt> + <PgUp>` → `\033[5;3~` and `<Alt> + <PgDn>` → `\033[6;3~`. Adding the reference [here](https://github.com/weechat/weechat/blob/57aa9e060ef7214f8b822fa32b40bb728482adce/src/gui/curses/gui-curses-key.c#L167-L170).

Comment: @Atcold -- Seems like you did enough investigation (you went to the source code!) to write (and accept) a distinct/correct answer.  You've been generous with your acknowledgements and gratitude that I don't feel slighted if my answer is not accepted.  I'm aware that it never correctly answered the problem.  Have you figured out why there are two entries for some keystrokes in that weechat table?

Comment: So, the keyboard is supposed to send `\033[5;3` upon pressing the `<Alt> + <PgUp>` combo. Nevertheless, it is acceptable for *WeeChat* to receive the combination of the two keys separately. It seems that "meta" represents `<Esc>`. That's why I was able to get by by using `<Esc><PgUp>`. So, I set that to be my first action hack. Finally, I figured the correct escape sequence that the program was expecting. I'll try to summarise all this in my answer. Thank you sempai!